# Busca PHP + SQL não encontra resultados sem digitar o hífen "-"

Tags: mysql, sql, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá!
Tenho uma busca de produtos automobilísticos onde o usuário pode procurar pelo código da empresa, código original, linha de produtos, montadora ou veículo.
Esse sistema está funcionando se no campo de busca eu digito, por exemplo, "E-1001", ou "1001", ou "E". Mas se eu digitar "E1001" sem o hifen, ele não retorna nenhum resultado.

O mesmo problema acontece no campo de código original. Se eu busco por exemplo "12.345.67", ou "12", ou "1" ele funciona. Mas não retorna nada se eu buscar "1234567" sem os pontos no meio.

Alguém teria ideia do que posso alterar para funcinar sem esses hífen e pontos?

Obrigado!

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){  
        $buscacodempresa = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?()!-]#i', '', $_POST['searchcodempresa']);  
        $buscacodoriginal = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?()!-.]#i', '', $_POST['searchcodoriginal']);  
        $idlinha = $_POST['parent_linha'];  
        $idmont = $_POST['parent_mont'];  
        $idveics = $_POST['parent_veics'];  

        if($_POST['parent_veics'] >= 1) {
            $getresultsquery = mysql_query('SELECT p.*, a.idProduto, a.idVeiculos, a.ano, v.nomeVeiculos, v.idVeiculos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.ano SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(a.idVeiculos SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(v.nomeVeiculos SEPARATOR "<br>")
            FROM produtos p
            INNER JOIN aplicacao a ON p.idProduto = a.idProduto
            INNER JOIN veiculos v ON a.idVeiculos = v.idVeiculos
            WHERE p.codEmpresa LIKE "%'.$buscacodempresa.'%"
            OR p.codOriginal LIKE "%'.$buscacodoriginal.'%"
            OR p.idLinha = "'.$idlinha.'"
            OR v.idVeiculos = "'.$idveics.'"
            GROUP BY p.codEmpresa') or die(mysql_error());
        } else {
            $getresultsquery = mysql_query('SELECT p.*, a.idProduto, a.idVeiculos, a.ano, v.nomeVeiculos, v.idVeiculos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.ano SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(a.idVeiculos SEPARATOR "<br>"), GROUP_CONCAT(v.nomeVeiculos SEPARATOR "<br>")
            FROM produtos p
            INNER JOIN aplicacao a ON p.idProduto = a.idProduto
            INNER JOIN veiculos v ON a.idVeiculos = v.idVeiculos
            WHERE p.codEmpresa LIKE "%'.$buscacodempresa.'%"
            OR p.codOriginal LIKE "%'.$buscacodoriginal.'%"
            OR p.idLinha = "'.$idlinha.'"
            OR p.idMontadoras = "'.$idmont.'"
            GROUP BY p.codEmpresa') or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Comment: A razão para isso que é em seu banco seus dados também deve estar salvos formatado. Então para esta correto não retornar pois ficaria uma comparação `12.345.67`(banco) ` == ` `1234567`(string). Para resolver isso você deve submeter o dado do banco ao mesmo tipo de formatação do texto que procuras.

Comment: Guilherme, no banco os dados estão como 12.345.67 e E-1001. Mas o código não deveria exibir o resultado mesmo faltando um ou outro caracter? Até porque estou usando o operador LIKE.

Comment: Não é bem assim que o like funciona. Vamos supor, a sua consulta gera, por exemplo, algo como '%E1001%'. O que você está dizendo para banco é: "procure qualquer registro que contenha 'E1001', da forma como está escrito, mas desconsidere o que vier antes ou depois desse valor (%)". Traria por exemplo, 'abcE1001', 'E1001abc' e 'abcE1001abc'. Mas não traria 'Eabc1001'.

Comment: Entendi Daniel, obrigado pela explicação.
Então no caso, haveria algum operador que faça essa busca no estilo "Eabc1001"? Ou uma forma de contornar seria editar o DB inserindo uma coluna prevendo uma busca mais genérica para retornar o resultado? 
Por exemplo, na tabela "produtos", criar uma coluna "generico" e na linha do E-1001, colocar o valor E1001 e acrescentar na SQL algo do tipo "OR p.generico LIKE "%'.$buscacodempresa.'%""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o Guilherme Lautert disse, você deve submeter a consulta a mesma formatação.
Uma forma mais prática (talvez não a mais performatica) que te atenderia seria limpar o campo a ser comparado tanto no PHP quanto no sql server.

No SQL server você poderia colocar:

```
 OR REPLACE(REPLACE(p.codOriginal, '.', ''), '-', '') LIKE "%'.$buscacodoriginal.'%"
```

Comment: Daniel, é que no caso é ao contrário. Os dados no db estão COM o hífen e o ponto, então o replace não funcionaria.
Eu teria que alterar o db tirando hífen e pontos, ou criar uma coluna com os dados sem hífen e ponto e adicionar essa opção de busca também no SQL.

Comment: O Replace é justamente no campo do SQL. O que eu faço é remover os possiveis pontos e hifens antes de comparar.
Mas claro, você pode sim alterar o banco removendo as colunas ou adicionar uma coluna 'sanitizada'. O que for mais conveniente.